# Resharper "Namespace Provider" option does not appear for my folders

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

When I click a folder in my solution, I am expecting to see a `Namespace Provider` option in the Properties window, which I want to set to false (to avoid some Resharper warning).

This option does not appear for any of the folders in my solution. It does appear for 2 of my colleagues, but not for me and one other colleague.

We are all using the same solution, on VS2013 (12.0.30110.00) with R# 8.2 (8.2.0.2160).

Could there be any R# setting that we may have turned on that disables this functionality?

---

**Edit 1:**  *to clarify, I am selecting actual folders as opposed to "solution folders"*.

---

**Edit 2:** *screenshot of brand new solution:*
[image]

Comment: What does your folder icon look like, if it's just a dotted outline then it is a file system folder (when you have 'Show All Files' turned on in your Solution Explorer). If it's a solid brown folder icon then you should have the Namespace Provider in your Properties.

Comment: @PiersMyers I am selecting actual folders in the file system which are in my solution (rather than "Solution Folders"). I can see them in my project even with Show All Files turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have TeamCity plugin installed in your Visual Studio? TeamCity plugin is a known root of all evil for such case http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-35714. And it will be fixed in new version of TeamCity plugin. As a possible solution for now - uninstall TeamCity plugin.

Comment: Yep I did have the TeamCity Addin installed. Uninstalled it through Add/Remove programs and restarted VS, and Namespace Provider is back! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a Resharper bug. I've logged it [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-412833). I'll update this answer if we get anywhere.

---

**Update:**
As mentioned by [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802385/alexander) there was a conflict between two JetBrains software.
The TeamCity Addin 8.0 was not friends with Resharper 8.2. Uninstalling the TeamCity Addin (via Add/Remove Programs) and restarting VS made everything work normally again.

Comment: I assume you have disabled or uninstalled Resharper to see if you have the same problem? Could it be any of the other extensions you have installed that your colleagues don't?

Comment: @PiersMyers I've reinstalled it yeah. As for the other extensions, I was hoping someone could elaborate what could cause it. I don't know if there's any way to find out without uninstalling them one by one, and that sounds painful :(